# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running TestNG xml file with configured ReportNG

Tags: reportng

I am a new to Selenium, running my first TestNG with configured ReportNG. I have performed all the following required steps. Please help with your inputs. Thanks!

1. Added the following JARs into the project
   guice 3.0
   Velocity 1.4
   reportng 1.1.4
2. Disabled default listeners for TestNG
3. Added ReportNG listeners to the xml

   XML file:

After running the .xml as TestNG suite, getting the following error. The class definition looks fine...a snapshot below...

```
  package SeleniumProject;

  <<Import statements go here>>

     public class Test1DemoautBookTicket {

        --------
     }


Error:
```

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.<init>
    (RuntimeInstance.java:160)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.<clinit>
    (RuntimeSingleton.java:95)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.setProperty(Velocity.java:117)
    at org.uncommons.reportng.AbstractReporter.<init>(AbstractReporter.java:62)
    at org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter.<init>(HTMLReporter.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.newInstance(ClassHelper.java:50)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeConfiguration(TestNG.java:914)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more`

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
   <suite name="FirstSelenium">
   <listeners>
     <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
     <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
   </listeners>
      <test name="Test1"> 
            <classes>
            <class name="SeleniumProject.Test1DemoautBookTicket"></class>
            </classes>
     </test>
    </suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the ReportNG jars from [jar-download.com](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=reportng&g=org.uncommons&v=1.1.4&downloadable=1).
Among the files was also a file named **velocity-dep-1.4.jar**. Before I added it to the project I got the same error as you.

(Disabling the default listeners doesn't seem necessary.)